# Implementing custom IdentifierGenerator with Hibernate for binary primary key in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Requirement - To have primary key in MySQL table of type binary(20) where first 4 bytes represent current timestamp (epoch in seconds) and rest of 16 bytes represent Type5 (name-based) UUID (stripped of dashes).

Ex. 57093200aee62cab765950a48ef887bcfe87a065 (57093200 is hex representation of epoch) and remaining is hex representation of UUID without dashes

I believe this is possible with hibernate 4.2+, but struggling to get a working model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "demo_table")
public class Request implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_id_generator", strategy = "com.company.id.Generator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_id_generator")  
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;

    :
}

public class Generator implements IdentifierGenerator {
     :
}
```

Need guidance here

Answer (score 0):

In your Generator class, you just need to implement the method

```
Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
```

of the *IdentifierGenerator* interface
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/id/IdentifierGenerator.html
(basically you can just return String formatted as you described)